# Can't add string from JSON parser in class Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

When I add to the class I can't use the string from json parse out of the for cycle or out of the json parser code...

I'm using volley to do the parser and I'm getting the info from the database, I just can't use this info out of the for cycle and out of the json parser code

```
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("" +
            "http://193.137.7.33/~estgv16392/XMLParse/JsonParse/json_parse.php", null,


            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        ArrayList<Respostas> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("perguntas");

                        for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject meldung = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            comment = meldung.getString("Resposta");

                            s_array[i] = comment;
                            System.out.println("Adicionar" + comment);
                            gestor_respostas.addresposta(10, comment, 0);

                            Respostas perguntas = new Respostas(10,meldung.getString("Resposta"),0);
                            listaaar.add(perguntas);





                        }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            },



            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });



    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Respostas Class:

```
package com.example.tonyferreira.app_perguntas;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by TonyFerreira on 31/12/17.
 */

public class Respostas {

int id_pergunta_resposta;
String resposta;
int tipo;
ArrayList<Respostas> lista_respostas = new ArrayList<>();

public Respostas(int id_pergunta_resposta, String resposta, int tipo){

    this.id_pergunta_resposta = id_pergunta_resposta;
    this.resposta = resposta;
    this.tipo = tipo;

}

public Respostas(){}

public void addresposta(int idpr, String per, int tip) {
    lista_respostas.add(new Respostas(idpr, per, tip));
}

public ArrayList<Respostas> devolve_respostas(){return lista_respostas;}

public int devolve_idpr(){return id_pergunta_resposta;}

public String devolve_resposta(){return resposta;}

public int devolve_tipo(){return tipo; }

}
```

So, what could I do ?

Comment: your json and on which part you are facing the problem

Comment: Im having here the problem in the for cycle.. Im adding to Respostas Class and when im returning the list from the class to a list in the main activity the list is null, and i dont know why...  for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {

Comment: your Json bro on which you are iterating over in string format paste here

Comment: paste your json response here

Comment: {"perguntas":[{"idRespostas":"68","Resposta":"Lisboa","tipo":"1","Pergunta_id_pergunta":"1"},{"idRespostas":"69","Resposta":"Porto","tipo":"0","Pergunta_id_pergunta":"1"},{"idRespostas":"70","Resposta":"Coimbra","tipo":"0","Pergunta_id_pergunta":"1"},{"idRespostas":"71","Resposta":"Leiria","tipo":"0","Pergunta_id_pergunta":"1"}]}